# Why does my javascript break anchors?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, anchor

I have a web page with a top link at the bottom, and anchor for it at the top of the page. I have the following JavaScript to make an element (`#primary_nav`) fixed after the page has been scrolled past that element:

```js
window.onscroll = scroll;
var scrollFlag = 0;

function scroll() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 120 && scrollFlag == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('content').style.margin = '35px auto 0 auto';
        document.getElementById('primary_nav').style.position = 'fixed';
        document.getElementById('primary_nav').style.top = '35px';
        document.getElementById('primary_nav').style.width = '100%';
        scrollFlag = 1;
    }
    else if(window.pageYOffset < 120 && scrollFlag == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById('content').style.margin = '0 auto';
        document.getElementById('primary_nav').style.position = 'static';
        document.getElementById('primary_nav').style.top = 'auto';
        document.getElementById('primary_nav').style.width = '1024px';
        scrollFlag = 0;
    }
}
```

If I disable this javascript, the link works fine and sends the user back to the top of the page. The anchor is not inside primary_nav or content.

The HTML elements are declared as follows:

```html
<a name='top'></a>
<a href='#top' id='backtotop' title='{$this->lang->words['go_to_top']}'><img src='{$this->settings['img_url']}/top.png' alt='' /></a>
```

**How can I have both the effect of the javascript** (sticky navigation) **and working anchor links?**

You can also check the [live site](http://forum.twisted-gamers.net/).

**So far I've tried**

- Moving the top anchor all over `<body>`
- Replacing the "Go to top" button's `href` with javascript (`window.location = '#top'` and `window.scrollTo(0,0)`) with both `href` and `onclick`. (Both of these work when put into console on Chrome)

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MuM7m/) indicates that it's caused by my script conflicting with something else. The only other script accessing it is:

```js
if($('backtotop')){$('backtotop').observe("click",function(e){Event.stop(e);window.scroll(0,0);});}
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with: `if($('backtotop')){$('backtotop').observe("click",function(e){Event.stop(e);window.scroll(0,0);});}`

Comment: @NickR where is that?

Comment: @3ventic it's in the middle of a huge wad of code on the page.

Comment: Can you break this down into a simpler test case and provide a Fiddle for it?

Comment: @3ventic Get `Firebug` or equivalent debugger, then go to the `script` tab, and search for `backtotop`, then you can see the `click` event that is being bound to that element

Comment: If you type `window.location.hash = 'branding'` into the console it goes to the top just fine. I'm not having the same lucky with 'top', though.

Comment: So it seems to be a conflict between my JS and the "huge wad of code"

Comment: Since you've proven that the JavaScript in your question is not actually causing the problem, I think you need to go back to your site and find out which JavaScript actually IS causing the problem.  You might be lucky and get some people interested in debugging your whole site, but I think you need to dig deeper yourself first (following the good advice given by others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own Javascript overwrote a function of the same name in the default scripts, which caused the failure. Renaming my scroll function fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out part of your issue.

I noticed I can't type `location.hash = 'top'` and have it jump to `top` unless I take it out of `#content_jump`. I assume this is because `#content_jump` is hidden.

It seems like there might be an event listener on all links that start with `#` that's causing the issue. I noticed most anchor links are doing little fancy things.